# Change Windows 7 Professional to Windows 7 Professional N

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have two Windows 7 Professional Licenses (Via MSDNAA)

But one license & key is for Win 7 Pro N and the other is for Win 7 Pro

My problem is, i am stuck in the countryside for the next month with a unreliable and very slow internet connection will take me a week to download a Win 7 Pro N disk. (which means using bit torrent, as my connection is too unreliable for FTP)

But i have a Win 7 Pro Disk, what do i need to do to make the disk install as N or do to modify it after i have installed as the N key wont work on the non N install. (i have Windows 7 Pro iso & setup as a USB stick install)

Does anyone know any tricks for this?

Solutions i have already tried and failed:
change ei.cfg so it says Professional N - causes the installer to fail to start
install and use N key anyway - Invalid License Key error.

Edit:
To make it clear i need to be able to use my N product key on a install done using a non-N disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say just install with your regular Win7 license. If it gives you trouble during installation because of the product key, just skip activation until the install is completed.

After installing, use the Activation wizard, except dial the 1-800 number. You'll have to enter a ton of digits, but eventually you'll get a person on the other end to talk to. Explain to them that you had to replace some parts in your PC and reinstall Windows. They'll approve the activation.

Then, when you get home, it may start bugging you about activation again. In which case, run the activation wizard, call and give them a similar story, say the replacement hard drive you bought went bad or something, and you can reactivate your regular PC. Back up the work you did on your other PC, and reinstall with Win7 N. Since you'd only be using one computer at a time with the license, I wouldn't lose sleep over the legality of it.

I used to do PC repair, and we always had to call up Microsoft when reintsalling after a hard drive or motherboard replacement unless we replaced it with the exact same type of part.

Comment: Ok thanks, as its only for a month, i might just use slmgr -rearm then reinstall when i get home. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Why need to go to N?

N versions are generally comparable to the non-N version except that N versions do not contain Windows Media Player.

Remove Media Player
Go to Turn windows features off in "Programs and Features" Select Media features and uncheck what you do not want.

Don't know if this is all that you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: Ok the problem is that i cannot use my N product key on a install done using a normal (non-N) disk. I dont want to use N but its the only spare license key i have

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you are not going to find an easy way to convert your Win 7 Pro disk to Win 7 Pro N. As you say you have tried the ei.cfg hack without success.

My suggestion is to install the Win 7 Pro disk without entering a serial number (it does let you). You can then use this for up to 4 months without entering a serial. You will have to use the "rearm" command (supported by ms) every 30 days.